# Docker for Laravel multi tenancy application -Error 502

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, multi-tenant, saas

I have configured a Docker setup consisting of multiple services: PHP, Nginx, MySQL, and Redis. My intention is to run a Laravel application using this configuration. However, when I execute docker-compose up, I encounter a "Bad Gateway" error. Here's an overview of my setup:

Dockerfile for PHP Service:

```bash
# Use the official PHP image as the base image with PHP 8.2
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json to install dependencies
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Install Composer (PHP dependency manager)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# Copy the Laravel application files to the working directory in the container
COPY . /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN composer install


# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9001
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Docker Compose File (`docker-compose.yml`):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx_container
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - app-network

    php:
        container_name: php_container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9001:9000"
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
        networks:
            - app-network

    mysql:
        container_name: mysql_container
        image: mysql:5.7
        platform: linux/amd64
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: zmenu
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - app-network

    redis:
        container_name: redis_container
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - app-network

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
        external: true

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Nginx Configuration (`nginx/default.conf`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.zmenu\.test$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://php:9001;
        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.zmenu.test;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Despite setting up the services and Nginx configuration, running docker-compose up results in a "Bad Gateway" error. I'm unsure why this error is occurring. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a `php-fpm` image you need `fastcgi_pass`; the protocol isn't HTTP.  Make sure to use the standard port number in connections between containers (probably `fastcgi_pass php:9000`), since `ports:` aren't used here (or required).

Comment: also PHP-FPM runs on port 9000 by default. You are not changing the default. You seem to be attempting to map the container port 9000 to the host port 9001 but when you use `http://php:9001` then the connection is done container to container. You still need to use 9000 for that